# How to read 3 dimensional parameter from Excel to GAMS?

Tags: optimization

I don't know it is the place to ask this GAMS question but I couldn't find any other source.

My question is about reading 3 dimensional parameter to GAMS from Excel file. I know it if there is a 2 dimensional parameter we should use;

```
parameter t(i, j)
$call GDXXRW data.xlsx par=t trace=3 cdim=1 rdim=1 rng=Sayfa1!A1
$GDXIN data.gdx
$LOAD t
$GDXIN
```

As the same way if we use:

```
parameter t(i,j,k)
$call GDXXRW data.xlsx par=t trace=3 cdim=1 rdim=1 rng=Sayfa1!A1
$GDXIN data.gdx
$LOAD t
$GDXIN
```

Then it says "LOAD dimensions are different". How can it be done? Is there someone has knowledge GAMS? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rdim+cdim` should be 3 in your case. So depending on how the data is layed out in Excel, you should have `rdim=1 cdim=2` or `rdim=2 cdim=1`.

E.g. for data like:

[image]

you would use `rdim=2 cdim=1`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did search for this for an hour and finally got it.